# what is the best approach to build an image annotation tool for computer vision object detection, in my react js app, which will be dockerized later

Tags: reactjs, computer-vision, annotations

My target is to build a web hosted app that will include an annotation tool, I am considering using existing tools, API's or Components, in which I will integrate in my web hosted solution, instead of building a tool from scratch.

My app is developed using react js, which will be later dockerized.

I tried to follow some tutorials for components in react js that offers some annotation functionalities, And now I am looking for better approaches.